# Open an installed application using react native / expo app (android)

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have **myself developed apk** (which is **not available in the play store**) **installed in my android system**. And I need to **open that app through the react-native / expo app on a button click event**. Is there any possibility to open that app through the react-native / expo app **without internet or linking to the PlayStore**?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Linking API](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#send-intents-android)  available in React native out of the box. Here is an example to open Whatsapp from your app using the URI scheme or you could use Explicit intents to open other apps using [Linking.sendIntent](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#send-intents-android).

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { Alert, Button, Linking, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

const OpenWhatsappButton = ({ action, children }) => {
const handlePress = useCallback(async () => {
try {
  await Linking.openURL(action);
  } catch (e) {
  Alert.alert(e.message);
 }
}, [action]);

return <Button title={children} onPress={handlePress} />;

};

const App = () => {
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <OpenWhatsappButton action="whatsapp://send?text=">
    Whatsapp
  </OpenWhatsappButton>
</View>
);
};

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: { flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" },
});

export default App;
```